# Chrome Lighthouse CLS audit providing significantly different results for different users

Tags: google-chrome, lighthouse, core-web-vitals, cumulative-layout-shift

In preparation for the next Core Web Vitals update, I am working on decreasing CLS across my companies site. When I run the Lighthouse audit in Chrome, the page I've updated gets a 0.05, under the max 0.1 Google recommends.

However, when my companies SEO specialist runs an audit, she gets scores > 0.3 on the same page. I'd thought maybe it could be a speed issue, but throttling my internet speed didn't change my results at all (at least where CLS is concerned). For that matter, the audit on her end is calling out high level parent div elements as causing high CLS, rather than specific elements within the parent div.

Is there any reason why her scores would be so much worse than mine on the same page? Are there any known issues with CLS testing in Lighthouse I should be aware of?

Comment: Screen size is most likely a factor if you are comparing the desktop site, if comparing the mobile site it could be that your computer or her computer are significantly different performance wise. Lighthouse applies a 4x CPU slowdown - so if a CPU is slow in the first place this could be one cause. Best advice would be to run the site through [Page Speed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) or [web.dev/measure](https://web.dev/measure) as they both use Lighthouse as the engine that powers them and results should be consistent (if not then that is a separate issue)

Comment: @GrahamRitchie It looks like this was indeed the case, my CLS scores for laptop drop quite a bit when I test on a larger monitor. Could you submit this as an answer?

Comment: Of course, all done! Glad you got to the bottom of it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If two different people are getting two different results there are numerous things to check.

The first one is to check that you are both testing at the same display size (for desktop tests - all mobile tests are same size) as otherwise one of you may get CLS at one breakpoint that does not occur at another breakpoint (or items may be on the screen on one device and not another that contribute to CLS).

The next thing to check is that the computers have a similar CPU power. Lighthouse uses a 4x slowdown when running the mobile test, if you have an i3 vs an i9 this can make quite a difference!

There is a useful document that explains [where variability can come from when testing with Lighthouse](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/blob/master/docs/variability.md).

Comment: Just to tack on to Graham's answer, Chrome's browser console was also impacting the page height, causing my scores to be different. My personal preference is to have the console pinned to the bottom (which reduced window height), while my coworker has it in a separate window. When testing CLS having the console in a seperate window seems like the best approach.